# How to loop an object and remove all functions from it

Tags: javascript, function

Let's get right the issue, I need to remove all functions from a object to send via socket.io JSON!
Let's say I have an object such as...

```
let myObject = {
    test1: "abc",
    test2: function() {
        console.log("This is a function");
    },
    test3: {
        test4: "another string",
        test5: function() {
            console.log("another function");
        },
        test6: 123
    }
}
```

and I need to convert it too

```
let myObject = {
    test1: "abc",
    test3: {
        test4: "another string",
        test6: 123
    }
}
```

I have tried many cod methods, all of which failed!
I would post them but that would be wasting your valuable time.
I'd love anyone who could fix this problem in a neat function manner.
Yours Truly, Jacob Morris

P.S. Here is a piece of c**p attempt at doing this

```js
let myObject = {
  test1: "abc",
  test2: function() {
      console.log("This is a function");
  },
  test3: {
      test4: "another string",
      test5: function() {
          console.log("another function");
      },
      test6: 123
  }
}

let i = [];
function tsfr(ls) {
    let i = {};
    for (let a in ls) {
        if (typeof(ls[a]) !== "function") {
            let d = ls[a];
            if (typeof(d) == "object") {
                d = tsfr(d);
            }
            i[a] = d;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
i = tsfr(myObject);
console.log(i)
```

Comment: Please show at least one of your attempts.

Comment: You can do it with the defineProperty method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @AnoopMc I looked at that earlier and didn't see anything that would remove all functions of an object

Comment: `myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))`

Comment: remove means delete or getting a new object without function?

Comment: @NinaScholz means new object with the functions and no functions in its branching objects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own recursive solution, but I think it is better to use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). By default stringify ignores functions and removes them from the result. In certain cases, it's second param, replacer function, can get handy for more advanced object manipulation.

```js
const removeFunctions = (obj) => {
  const stringified = JSON.stringify(obj);

  // We need to parse string back to object and return it
  const parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);

  return parsed;
}

const myObject = {
    test1: "abc",
    test2: function() {
        console.log("This is a function");
    },
    test3: {
        test4: "another string",
        test5: function() {
            console.log("another function");
        },
        test6: 123
    }
}

console.log(removeFunctions(myObject));
```

(Or on [codepen](https://codepen.io/stanko/pen/BvrYqZ?editors=1111))

Please note that stringifying uses `toString()` method, and for some instances of custom classes can lead to a data loss. To prevent that, you'll need to write your own, recursive solution. It is probably going to be a lot more complicated.

Hope this helps, cheers!

EDIT: I just saw your attempt. It is a step in right direction, but it needs some more love. But I need to advise you against variable names like `tsfr` or `ls`. Code is much more readable if you use longer, more descriptive names.

EDIT2: As pointed by Andreas in the comments, you don't even need custom replacer as stringify ignores them and removes them by default.

Comment: Thanks! Tried it in my code and it works like a charm!

Comment: You don't need a _custom replacer function_. JSON doesn't support functions, hence they are ignored/removed automatically.

Comment: Heh, thank you! I totally missed that, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the key/value pairs by type checking and later map new object by checking the nested objects.

```js
const
    removeFn = object => Object.assign(...Object
        .entries(object).filter(([k, v]) => typeof v !== 'function')
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v && typeof v === 'object' ? removeFn(v) : v }))
    );

var object = { test1: "abc", test2: function() { console.log("This is a function"); }, test3: { test4: "another string", test5: function() { console.log("another function"); }, test6: 123 } };

console.log(removeFn(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and recursively remove nested object properties it like this:

```js
let myObject = {
  test1: "abc",
  test2: function() {
    console.log("This is a function");
  },
  test3: {
    test4: "another string",
    test5: function() {
      console.log("another function");
    },
    test6: 123
  }
}

const deleteFunctions = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
    if (typeof obj[k] === "function")
      delete obj[k];
    else if (typeof obj[k] === "object")
      deleteFunctions(obj[k])
  })
}

deleteFunctions(myObject)

console.log(myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I'd do it this way. This is a revisitation of Douglas Crockford's DOM algorithms.

First, a recursive function (`visit()`) that visits an arbitrary object and applies an arbitrary function to each member:

```
function visit(obj, func)
{
  for (k in obj)
  {
    func(obj, k);

    if (typeof obj[k] === "object")
    {
      visit(obj[k], func);
    }
  }
}
```

This is a working example with a payload function that just outputs found functions to the console:

```js
var testdata = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": "hello",
  "c": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  "d": (x) => 2 * x,
  "e": null,
  "f": {
    "x": 10,
    "y": {
      "z": "$$$",
      "zz": (x) => 0
    }
  }
};

function visit(obj, func)
{
  for (k in obj)
  {
    func(obj, k);
    
    if (typeof obj[k] === "object")
    {
      visit(obj[k], func);
    }
  }
}

visit(testdata, (obj, k) => {
  if (typeof obj[k] === "function")
  {
    console.log(k + " is a function");
  }
});
```

As the code above shows, the payload function `func` is able to find all and only functions in the object.

All we need now is a function that removes the member, but this is very easy now:

```
(obj, k) => {
  if (typeof obj[k] === "function")
  {
    delete obj[k];
  }
}
```

By separating the visit from the payload you can reuse this in many ways and manipulate recursively objects for all kinds of necessities...

Answer (score 0):

It will remove all the function from the above object

```
function removeFuncFromObj(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "function") {
        delete obj[key];
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] === typeof {}) {
        removeFuncFromObj(obj[key]);
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
removeFuncFromObj(myObject);
```

[https://jsbin.com/favikej/edit?js,console,output][1]

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, so no need for parenthesis: `typeof obj[key]`. `typeof(function() {})` is inefficient and unnecessary, it will **always** return `'function'`.